# InheritedWidget becomes null on Navigator route change

Tags: flutter

I'm using an InheritedWidget to keep track of auth state. It works fine on main app. But as soon as I go to another page via a route change, the components in the new route cannot find the inherited widget.

Ideally, I would like all pages/routes to share the same auth state.

The following minimal example gives a NULL pointer error.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(EntryPoint());

class TestContext extends InheritedWidget {
  const TestContext({
    Key key,
    Widget child,
  }) : super(key: key, child: child);

  final String hello = "foobar";

  static TestContext of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(TestContext) as TestContext;
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(TestContext oldWidget) => true;
}

class EntryPoint extends StatelessWidget {
  /// Needed for dialog
  final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
        title: 'TODO',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: TestContext(
            child: Scaffold(
                body: Center(
                    child: Builder(
                        builder: (context) => FlatButton(
                            child: Text('Launch'),
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => LoginForm()),
                              );
                            }))))));
  }
}

class LoginForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  LoginFormState createState() {
    return LoginFormState();
  }
}


class LoginFormState extends State<LoginForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Build a Form widget using the _formKey created above.
    return Scaffold(
        body: Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Enter your JIRA website URL'),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.url,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 28,
                initialValue: TestContext.of(context).hello,
              ),             
            ],
          )),
    ));
  }
}
```

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building LoginForm(dirty, state: LoginFormState#be3a1):
The getter 'hello' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: hello

User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was
    MaterialApp 
package:flutter_greeting_screen/main.dart:63
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      Object.noSuchMethod  (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
#1      LoginFormState.build 
package:flutter_greeting_screen/main.dart:144
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `Navigator.of(context).push(...)` or `Navigator.push(context, ...)` or `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(...)` or `Navigator.pushNamed(context, ...)`, the widget pushed is not a child of the widget that call `Navigator.push` (and its variants), this widget is a child of the closest instance of `Navigator` that encloses the given `context`, in your case the `Navigator` is created by the `MaterialApp`, so if you want to provide `TestContext` to all routes, the `InheritedWidget` must be a parent of the `Navigator`, in your case must be a parent of `MaterialApp`.

```dart
class EntryPoint extends StatelessWidget {
  /// Needed for dialog
  final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TestContext(
      child: MaterialApp(
          navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
          title: 'TODO',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          home: Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                  child: Builder(
                      builder: (context) => FlatButton(
                          child: Text('Launch'),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => LoginForm()),
                            );
                          }))))),
    );
  }
}
```

I also recommend that you look at `Provider` widget of the [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package, which is a widget with syntax sugar for `InheritedWidget`.

> A generic implementation of InheritedWidget. It allows to expose any kind of object, without having to manually write an InheritedWidget ourselves.

```dart
Provider<String>.value(
  value: 'Hello World',
  child: MaterialApp(
    home: Home(),
  )
)
```

```dart
Provider<Auth>(
  builder: (context) => Auth(),
  dispose: (context, auth) => auth.dispose(),
  child: MaterialApp(
    home: Home(),
  )
)
```